# How does the pipe (|) in dplyr work in the context of Shiny and datatables?

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, datatables

I have a basic recreation of the component of an app that I am building in Shiny here:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

test <- as.data.frame(structure(state.abb, names=state.name))
test <- tibble::rownames_to_column(test, "state_name")
names(test)[2] <- "state_abb"
statedata <- tibble::rownames_to_column(as.data.frame(state.x77), "state_name")
globaldata <- merge(statedata,test, by.x = "state_name", by.y = "state_name")


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("states", "States:", sort(c("All states"="", structure(state.abb, names=state.name), "Washington, DC"="DC", "Puerto Rico" = "PR")), multiple=TRUE),
  dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  filterData <- reactive({
    globaldata %>% filter(is.null(input$states) | state_abb %in% input$states) #how does this work???
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    filterData()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is exactly the functionality that I am going for with the state filter but I am very confused about how the reactive dataframe works i.e., what condition is being resolved inside the filter statement. Technically, the `is.null` condition is being met to return the full table when no specific states are selected but there is no value in `input$states` that is `NULL`. `"All states" = ""` which is not equal to `NULL` so why is that condition being met?

Comment: Suggest starting your first reactive with `req(input$states)`, as it will skip the reactive block unless/until `input$states` passes `shiny::isTruthy` (e.g., not null, not NA, not empty-list, etc). You might also change your second block to `renderDataTable({ req(filterData()) })`, since `req` returns the value of the first test and will stop the data table from looking wonky during shiny spool-up.

Comment: From `?selectInput` _selected 
The initially selected value (or multiple values if multiple = TRUE). If not specified then defaults to the first value for single-select lists and no values for multiple select lists._ As here `multiple=TRUE`, the initial value ends up as `NULL`